# Xamarin Forms allow music from another app on Android while playing Video

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing the issue, that my App Blocks Background Music when using a MediaElement for Video usage.
The bottom line is that I want to play a silent video and the user should still be able to listen to spotify and etc. in the background
In iOS the procedure to allow Background Music is pretty straight forward. On Android I cannot manage to get it working.

I already tried different xamarin.forms libraries where i set the video to mute or the volume to zero.
But nothing seemed to work. I tried for example octane, mediamanager and several other videoplayers.

For this reason, I would now like to try to implement it in the native Android code.
But I haven't found anything about it in various forums.

Xamarin Forms Version is 4.8

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service to stream audio to play audio while your application is not visible or under the lock screen.

You could check the blog about this and download the source file from the Github. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin-android/

I test with the sample in the thread i done before to play the audio. [libVLCsharp.forms can not play Android resource video file while iOS can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547427/libvlcsharp-forms-can-not-play-android-resource-video-file-while-ios-can)

When i make the app which play music in the background, the music would play as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what i want is the other way around. Iwant that my app doesn't block the sound from other apps. Right now when i start a Video in my App themusic of other apps (e.g. spotify) gets stopped. But i want that it keeps playing.

Comment: We could not make the changes for the spotify.  You could create your own app to play the music in the background.